# Parse a date from a format like: "%B %d, %Y" to a format: "%Y-%m-%d" in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I'd like to convert in R a string vector of dates like this:

```
[1] "March 21, 2016"    "March 9, 2016"     "March 1, 2016"     "February 29, 2016" "January 26, 2016"  "December 15, 2015" "December 14, 2015"
 [8] "November 9, 2015"  "October 13, 2015"  "August 26, 2015"   "August 10, 2015"
```

to a vector of dates like this:

```
[1]  "2016-03-21" "2016-03-09" 
.....
```

I've already tried, without success, to parse the string using:

```
library(lubridate)    
format(mdy(dates),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

and using:

```
as.Date(dates, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

In both cases the result is a string of NA.
What's wrong?

Comment: It may depend on your locale. What's the output of `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: "LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252"

Comment: That's the problem. I made an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `locale` expects names of the months to be in italian. Since they are in English in your object, the dates are not parsed. For instance, this should work for you (luckily I'm Italian too):

```
dates <- "Marzo, 21 2016"
library(lubridate)    
format(mdy(dates),"%Y-%m-%d")
#[1] "2016-03-21"
```

To parse your dates, you have to change the locale:

```
#register the old locale to set it back
OL <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
#set the new locale
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","C")
dates <- "March, 21 2016"
format(mdy(dates),"%Y-%m-%d")
#[1] "2016-03-21"
#Change the locale back to the old value
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", OL)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the correct `Date` values. Try this:

```
as.Date(dates, "%B %d, %Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d<-"March 21, 2016"
parse_date_time(d, orders="%B %d, %Y")
```